# ImageJpeg() - resource required, string given

Tags: php, gd, nsdata

How can I write an NSData (received from an iOS Device) to a file path in PHP?

I tried the following method, but I am getting a warning regarding the format of the

> imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
function store_question_image($blob) {
    $blob = 'ffd8ffe000104a46494600010201004800480000f....'; //9975 chars
    $filepath = "localhost/citw/img/questions/{$qid}/attachment.png";
    return imagejpeg($blob, $filepath);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imagejpeg() takes a GD resource handle (aka the in-memory representation of a GD image) and writes it out as a jpeg. You've got what looks to be base64 data(?) of some sort.

You could use `imagecreatefromstring($blob)` to convert that text into a GD handle, but first you'll have to convert that text into the actual raw binary bytes of the image data, not this encoded format that GD will not know how to handle.